# how to pass data from one application to another in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I want to pass data from one application to another in Laravel..

Suppose I want to take user data from one application and I want to send this data to another application form.

I wanted to send it this way..But I'm getting Error..
So if anyone could suggest any solution for this..would be appreciated ..

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $payment = new Payment();
        $payment->username = $request->Input(['username']);
        $payment->price = $request->Input(['price']);
        $payment->purchase_id = $request->Input(['purchase_id']);
        $payment->save();
        $store_id =\Hash::make($payment->id);
        $price = $payment->price; 

        return \Redirect::to('http://localhost/blog/public/getPayment');
    }
```

And I get the following Error:

> ```
> InvalidArgumentException in Response.php line 462:
> The HTTP status code "0" is not valid.
> ```

Comment: Laravel uses CSRF-fields to stop this kind of thing. Did you disable csrf?

Answer (score 2):

If you just want your user to be redirected to another app so they can fill whatever forms you can use

```
return Redirect::away('http://localhost/blog/public/getPayment');
```

See the method [here](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Routing/Redirector.php#L129).

**BUT**

If you want to send data to another app without redirecting the user, the best solution I can give is to make an API on this other app so you can make requests (with Guzzle or something else) to this API, allowing you to pass some data.